# How to restructure return data in serializer django rest framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

Model.py

```
class CommentStruct(models.Model):
     type = models.CharField(nax_length=100)
     value= models.CharField(nax_length=100)
```

serializer.py

```
    class Meta:
         model = CommentStruct
         fields = '__all__'
```

Now I am getting format is

```
[{ 'type': 'comment', 'value':'hai'},
{ 'type': 'action', 'value':'no action'},
{ 'type': 'comment', 'value':'hallo'},
{ 'type': 'comment', 'value':'hello'},
{ 'type': 'action', 'value':'shake hand'}
]
```

what I want is
`[{ 'comment': ['hai','hallo','hello'], 'action':['no action', 'shake hand']}]`

I want to restructure data in the model serializer

Comment: This actually looks to me more like a modeling problem. You can make a `CommentType` and work with a `ForeignKey` from `Comment` to `CommentType`, in that case you thus serialize the `CommentType` with a related serializer.

Comment: Ya, but the model has few values that's why created as single model

Comment: if there are a limited number of types, then this is all more reason to work with an extra model, since then the *data duplication* is more prominent.

Comment: Can reform to that form using this model?